# Unusual Voltage Spike at minimum Voltage Peak

Tags: operational-amplifier

I recently started to get into electronics. I am messing arround with amplifiers right now. I’m trying create a unity gain amplifier. I hooked the amp up to a dc supply then threw in an AC signal and measure the input and output voltage on an oscilloscope.

This spike will cause a lot of issues when I construct an active low pass filter. Any ideas on why this is there?

I attached some pictures to help. I marked the dc supply input and this is a LM358 Dual Op Amp. Thanks!

[image][image]

Comment: Decouple your IC. Put a 0.1uF capacitor as close as possible across the power rails. It provides a low-inductance on-demand charge supply for the chip so it doesn't have to try to draw current from far away through inductance. I don't understand what your oscilloscope is supposed to be showing though.

Comment: The blue is my output voltage and underneath is the input voltage. My intended result of producing the exact same waveform is fine but this weird spike is going to mess a lot up for me in the future.

Comment: If the schematic is in one of the images, it did not come through.  If you did not post a schematic, that will affect the quality of the responses.

Comment: That is strange, the schematic shows up for me. However, @Toor YOU WERE RIGHT. That makes perfect sense too I appreciate it! Idk how to make that the accepted answer but it 100% fixed it!

Comment: I guess I'm confused because you said you put an AC signal into your circuit and on the scope there is an AC sinusoid plus two triangle looking things that are similar to each other but don't look sinusoidal at all. I was kind of expecting to just see two waveforms: An input AC sinusoid, and a an output not-so-sinusoid.

Comment: A photo of your breadboard is not a schematic. A schematic is the diagram which represents the circuit you're trying to build.

Comment: @Toor I should have separated the two signals the Voltage input signal is underneath the blue signal. Those weird triangle things are not supposed to be there. I think it was high frequency noise that was showing up.

Comment: @brhans You are right I apologize I was not thinking properly. Like I said, I am trying to get more into electronics as it will help me with my job further down the road.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Decouple your IC. Put a 0.1uF capacitor as close as possible across the power rails. It provides a low-inductance on-demand charge supply for the chip so it doesn't have to try to draw current from far away through inductance.

This is standard practice for all ICs. The higher frequency the IC is, the more it matters.